# How do I keep the debugger alive using lldb and VSCode to use it along with bitcoind & bitcoin-cli?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, bitcoin, lldb

All this is on Mac OS Mojave. There are two relevant executables in bitcoin: `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-cli`. bitcoind runs the bitcoin server.bitcoin-cli is used to execute transactions and other activities.  I would like trace the transaction which is initiated by `bitcoin-cli`

I have already been able to trace the path of `bitcoind` using `lldb`. I am trying to trace the path of execution of transaction made using `bitcoin-cli`. When I run `bitcoind` using `lldb` and Visual Studio code the "debugger panel" disappears if I dont put in a break point. I cant put a break point when I make the transaction using `bitcoin-cli` because the debugger panel disappears. You can see the debugger panel on the top left [image here](https://ibb.co/DRRhsh7) which disappears immediately

Here is the launch file of VS Code:

```
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/Users/ravi/zagg/micro-tests/bitcoin/src/bitcoind",
            "args": ["-datadir=/Users/ravi/zagg/micro-tests/bitcoin/datadir"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
```

How can I keep the debuggger alive so that I can trace an transactions i make using `bitcoin-cli`?

Comment: presumably it is running as a daemon in the background so when you launch it it forks itself and then the first process terminates. I can't see an option to turn this off in the command line arguments.The easiest thing is probably to attach to the process instead

Comment: Can you please elaborate on attaching to the process?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an issue with VScode or `lldb`. You are running bitcoin in daemon mode. You should change the configuration of bitcoin in `bitcoin.conf` from `daemon=1` to `daemon=0`. This will keep the debugger running. There should not be any more issues after that.